# Python - How Do I Make Relative Imports Compatible with Nose

Tags: python, python-import, nose

I am working on a package which has a folder structure like:

```
Root
 |---Source
 |---Testing
      |---Test_Utils
            |---test_fixtures.py
      |---test_integration.py
      |---test_unit.py
```

There are a fair amount of relative references flying around (e.g. in test_integration.py I need to import classes from the files in the Source folder as well as test harnesses and data from the Test_Utils folder.

So far I've managed this by using complete references e.g.:

`from Root.Testing.Test_Utils.test_fixtures import *`

Which seemed to work fine until actually trying to run `nosetests`. This is because nose seems only to find test files in the active directory (not the root working directory), so I have to `cd Testing` before running `nosetests`.. at which point the relative references break with:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Root'
```

How can I get round this seeming incompatibility (without using pytest, since I am using test generators (i.e. using yield) which I believe are deprecated in pytest)?

Comment: check your `PYTHON_PATH`

Comment: Could you expand on that? Also I suspect that's a user-level change, when I would like to distribute this, so would not want users to have to amend their environment variables before it works!

Answer (score 0):

[PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) sets the search path for importing python modules.

If you are using (Mac or GNU/Linux distro), add this to your `~/.bashrc`.

```
# add this line to ~/.bashrc
export PYTHONPATH=PYTHONPATH:/path/to/folder # path where is your Root folder

# after this we need to reload ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc

# if source ~/.bashrc don't work simple restart your terminal

# after this we can echo out our PYTHONPATH environment variable to check if it was added successfully
$ echo PYTHONPATH

# it need to output your folder
```